# Compare two vectors of same size in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I need to write a code which compares two vectors – one containing the reference values and the other one obtained values after some classification process – of the same size, and results in a confidence matrix which shows which elements, and how many of them are misclassified. 
Lets say the vectors are:
 `ref = [3;3;3;4;4;2;1;3]` and
 `obt = [4;2;3;1;1;3;4;3]`
I want the confidence matrix to be:`[0 0 0 1; 0 0 1 0;0 1 2 1 ;2 0 0 0]`
How to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the formulation for the confidence matrix? How do you calculate it?

Comment: I'm still lost at how the confidence matrix was calculated.

Comment: Never mind. I get it.  Each pair of `ref/obt` values is a row/column pair that is needed to access the confidence matrix.  For each time you see this row/column pair, you tally up a count that is seen at this matrix.  In the future, please provide explanation on how this matrix is calculated in the future.  It is not our job to try and guess or infer what you are trying to ask.  We help you solve problems, but in order to do that, you have to give us as much as possible to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make use of [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

- If **possible values are always of the form `1`, `2`, `3`, ...**:

  ```
  ref = [3;3;3;4;4;2;1;3]; %// original values
  obt = [4;2;3;1;1;3;4;3]; %// what the original values have been classified as

  vals = 1:max([ref(:) obt(:)]); %// all possible values
  result = accumarray([ref(:) obt(:)],1);
  ```
- If **values are arbitrary**:

  ```
  obt = [.1 .1 5.4 5.4 3 2.2 2.2]; %// original values
  ref = [.1 2.2 2.2 5.4 5.4 3 3]; %// what the original values have been classified as

  vals = unique([ref(:);obt(:)]); %// all existing values
  [~, refv] = max(bsxfun(@eq, ref(:).', vals(:)));
  [~, obtv] = max(bsxfun(@eq, obt(:).', vals(:)));
  result = accumarray([refv(:) obtv(:)],1);
  ```

Input vectors can be rows or columns interchangeably.

`vals` contains of all possible values (`[1 2 3 4]` in your example). `result(m,n)` indicates *how many times the value `vals(m)` has been classified as `vals(m)`*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. but is there any simpler way to do that? I am quite new in MATLAB and your code is unfortunately somehow difficult for me to understand. I have a feeling that a for loop with 'length' and 'find' would work as well, but I can not figure it out.

Comment: @NewProg Sure, it can be done with a loop, which is easier to understand for Matlab beginners. Are your values always of the form 1, 2, 3, ...?

Comment: I tried to simplify my question by choosing shorter vectors and less classes. Actually, they are all digits from 0 to 9, and the vectors are of dimension 60000X1.

Comment: @IKavanagh Indeed, I was mixing variables between the two versions. Thanks for the editing!

Answer (score 2):

```
num_classes = max([ref;obt]);
mat_classes = zeros(num_classes);

for i = 1:length(ref)
    mat_classes(ref(i),obt(i)) = mat_classes(ref(i),obt(i))+1
end
```

This should do what you want in a simpler way.

This is much more inefficient than Luis Mendo's response. For loops in matlab are usually not a good idea. If you are planning to use matlab often you should use vectorization.

Check this as a starter http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems more understandable to me.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Use Matlab's [confusionmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html) funcion:

```
>> confusionmat(ref, obt)
ans =

     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     2     1
     2     0     0     0
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `confusionmat` is part of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.

Comment: Perfect! But how can one be aware of such functions in MATLAB?